# How to get Image height within the div in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my page I have a `div` where `width` is **fixed** and `height` is **not fixed**. When I upload `500 X 300` image it will sit correctly within div, i.e here **width>height**. If I upload image with `10000 X 3000`,image height will become less than the 500 X 300 image, even if the second image height is more.

I am trying to do re-position with fixed `div` height. If the image height within the `div` after putting into the `div` is less then the re-position div height, I will not do re-position, otherwise my image quality will loose.

So how can I get the image height within the `div` using JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: Set the image `maxHeight = 500px;`..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just Use `.height()` method

```js
var imageheight = $(".imgclass img").height();
alert(imageheight);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imgclass">
<img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/images/1.png">
</div>
```

Comment: why my ans vote down??

Comment: somebody doesn't like the answers

Comment: @Shehary Thanks for amendment

Comment: wow, answer accepted , :D, you are welcome.

Comment: Hi @HumairaNaaz, why you deleted your answer from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944253/showing-mysql-rows-content-in-html-table-using-php

Comment: because you have problem with me

Answer (score 2):

To get the height of the image inside a div you can use

```
$("div img").height()
```

If you have a class or id for your div then use

```
$(".className img").height()
```

Also `specify the width alone` and the height be rendered automatically preserving the image aspect ratio. Specifying both height and width will skew the image