# Showing mysql rows content in html table using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm new here and I have a question, I looked for the solution everywhere and I still cant manage to solve this.

I want to show the results of the SELECT statement (in php) in a table (html) using JS. Here is the code of these 3 files:

**main.HTML file**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script> 
    <script src="select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="button"> Mostrar </button>
<br>
<input type="text" id="id" />
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**select.PHP file**

```
<?php
$link=mysqli_connect("xxxxxxx", "user_tienda","%%%%%%%%","pool_tiendas");

if (mysqli_connect_errno() )
    echo "Fallo en la conexion con mysql" .mysqli_connect_error();

$action=$_POST["action"];
if ($action=="showroom") {
    $query = "SELECT cod, nmbre, drccn from tienda";
    $show = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die ("error");
    echo "<table border='2px'><tr><td>cod</td><td>nmbre</td><td>drccn</td</tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($show)) {

        echo "<tr><td>" .$row['cod']."</td><td>".$row['nmbre']."</td><td>".$row['drccn']."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

**select.JS file**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function () {

        function show_all() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "select.php",
                data:{action:"showroom"},
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#id").hide();
                    $("#content").html(data);
                }
            });
        }

        show_all();
    });
});
```

The problem is when I click the button to show the content nothing happens.

The Select statemnt is correct, in Mysql font I can see the results of the SELECT statement.

> This is what I'm getting if I directly run select.php:
>   codnmbredrccn"; while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($show)) { echo "" .$row['cod']."".$row['nmbre']."".$row['drccn'].""; } echo ""; } ?>
>
> Now in mozilla console I can see 2 errors: no se encuentra elemento select.php:18 and no se encuentra elemento main.html:18 (no se encuentra elemento -> can't find element

The button is supposed to hide when clicked, but nothing happens. Seems like it never executes the js file.

Comment: just keep `alert()` in ajax success() and see whats happening..

Comment: Tried the "alert" thing if success and also if not success but nothing happens, its like the JS file its never executing (these 3 files are in the same folder) any ideas?

Comment: call the select.php directly from the browser's url bar manually and let us know if you see any error messages there.

Comment: codnmbredrccn"; while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($show)) { echo "" .$row['cod']."".$row['nmbre']."".$row['drccn'].""; } echo ""; } ?> thats what i get if i do that Shadow

Comment: Can you pls confirm that you are getting the php code as an output when you call the select.php file? If yes, then the php code is either not called through your webserver (you used direct file path as url) when you debugged it, or your webserver is not configured to run php code.

Comment: how can i confirm that? select.php is called from select.js file as POST type. edit: Now in mozilla console i can see 2 errors: no se encuentra elemento select.php:18 and no se encuentra elemento main.html:18 (no se encuentra elemento -> cant find element

Comment: what error occur in console?

Comment: cant find element (php line 18)
cant find element (html line 18)

Comment: check whether your select.js and jquery.js are present in same folder and not in other folder. ? because in head, you declared in the same folder where your main.html and select.php are present.

Comment: yep these 3 files are in the same folder.

Comment: Change the password on your server. Who knows how many places this has been mirrored by now?

Answer (score 0):

In this line

`echo "<table border='2px'><tr><td>cod</td><td>nmbre</td><td>drccn</td</tr>";`

The final `</td>` is missing a `>`

Comment: Thanks for that, solved. But the main problem persist

Comment: What do you see now when you go direct to select.php?

Comment: same thing: codnmbredrccn"; while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($show)) { echo "" .$row['cod']."".$row['nmbre']."".$row['drccn'].""; } echo ""; } ?>

Comment: Are you sure? Have you cleared the browser cache? Because the first part of the PHP script is working, so your server is processing PHP. It only stops working at exactly that point where the missing > was

Comment: Or you are missing a ' or " somewhere maybe

Comment: i think its never executing the js file. its supposed to hide the button when i click, but not even that happens

Answer (score 0):

Everything is perfect in your script if you are sure about your mysql details.
Please check your js files getting included in script.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yep im sure about the mysql details. I just included that line but same thing happens

Comment: @aarohi jquery file is included at very top of head section

Answer (score 0):

I removed jquery.js and inserted another script at head. It worked for me.
I connected it to localhost. check it.

**main.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="button"> Mostrar </button>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="id" />
    <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**select.js**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button").click(function () {

            function show_all() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "select.php",
                    data:{action:"showroom"},
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#id").hide();
                        $("#content").html(data);
                    }
                });
            }

            show_all();
        });
    });
```

**select.php**

```
<?php
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","manishYii");

if (mysqli_connect_errno() )
    echo "Fallo en la conexion con mysql" .mysqli_connect_error();

$action=$_POST["action"];
if ($action=="showroom") {
    $query = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, EmailID from members";
    $show = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die ("error");
    echo "<table border='2px'><tr><td>cod</td><td>nmbre</td><td>drccn</td</tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($show)) {

        echo "<tr><td>" .$row['FirstName']."</td><td>".$row['LastName']."</td><td>".$row['EmailID']."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: I also tried with `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` but the problem persists. Also tried with `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>` and downloading the js (jquery.js) but the problem is there ..

Comment: check your connection here $link=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","manishYii"); @RhsKPepper

Comment: @RhsKPepper. Then. database connection is having problem.

Comment: in $link=mysqli_connect("xxxxxxx", "user_tienda","%%%%%%%%","pool_tiendas"); what is there in place of xxxxxxx. Check user id and password and database name correctly. pool_tiendas is your database name ? check it properly. Because, i pasted your same code. and, it worked for me. So, only thing left is your database connection. Check it properly peacefully @RhsKPepper

Comment: I only changed my database connection.

Comment: in that case the `if (mysqli_connect_errno() )
    echo "Fallo en la conexion con mysql" .mysqli_connect_error();` should ve executed and it isnt.

Im 100% sure about the sql details

Comment: Then sorry. I Can't help @RhsKPepper

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($show)) {

    echo "<tr><td>" .$row['cod']."</td><td>".$row['nmbre']."</td><td>".$row['drccn']."</td></tr>";
}
```

or

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($show)) {

    echo "<tr><td>" .$row['0']."</td><td>".$row['1']."</td><td>".$row['2']."</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Hi @Syed. What is the difference ? only column number instead of column name. This will not make any difference.